# forward to a tab from java servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my JSP page I have some tabs. Each tab containing some form fields. When I click on the submit button, it calls a servlet. Is there any way to goto the next tab from servlet after the servlet is processed.

Here is my code for `index.jsp` for tabs and the first Tab

```
<div class="span12">
        <div class="navbar btn-navbar">
            <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#datacollector" target="main"
                        data-toggle="tab">Data Collector</a></li>
                    <li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromDatabase" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Database</a></li>
                    <li id="fromFile" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromFiles" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            File</a></li>
                    <li id="email" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromEmail" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Email</a></li>
                    <li id="webServices" class="selectDataloadType"
                        style="display: none;"><a href="#fromWebServices"
                        target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load Web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#datamap" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data
                            Map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#schedule" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="datacollector">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span8">
                                    <form name="selectType" action="selectType" method="get">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <label class="control-label" for="dataloadType">Data
                                                load Type:</label> <select id="dataloadType" name="dataloadType">
                                                <option>Choose Data load Type</option>
                                                <option value="fromDB">From Database</option>
                                                <option value="fromFile">From File</option>
                                                <option value="email">E-mail</option>
                                                <option value="webServices">Web Services</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <p>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                            </p>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

So when I click on the submit button it will call the servlet. And in my servlet I am processing something. And after that I want the servlet to redirect to the same `index.jsp` and to the next tab
In my servlet I tried this

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp#fromDatabase");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

But it was not working. Is there any way?

**UPDATE 1 after trying the solution given by @JB Nizet**

Here is my *LI* code

```
<li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType <c:if test="${activeTab == 'fromDatabase'}">active</c:if>" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromDatabase" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Database</a></li>
```

And then it shows the following in my index.jsp

[image]

I know this is because of double quotes. I am not able to rectify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet should simply decide which tab must be active and store this information in a request attribute before forwarding to the JSP. For example:

```
request.setAttribute("activeTab", "fromDatabase");
```

And the JSP should use this information to make the appropriate tab active. For example:

```
<li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType <c:if test="${activeTab == 'fromDatabase'}">active</c:if>" ...
```

(and similarly for the tab content)

Comment: Thanks. But it seems to be a problem when I open index.jsp in browser. Please see the update 1 in the question

Comment: Check the generated HTML code (view page source in your browser). Make sure the JSTL core taglib is declared in your JSP.

Comment: So do I have to download that jstl jar and include to my library and include the following code to my JSP?

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: Yes. Follow the instructions of the page I linked to.