# Set class attribute for a tag in JSP using session attribute from Servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

How to set a class attribute if some condition is true in a tag in JSP?
In my JSP page I have some tabs. In the first tab I have a form field and after submission, it will call servlet, process it and then it will forward to the same JSP page and will set a session attribute value *(say the id of next Tab)* And in my JSP page in the **LI** tag I am setting the class attribute to active if the string got from session attribute is some value.
But I am not able to get it.

Here is part of servlet code

```
String dataloadType=request.getParameter("dataloadType");
if(dataloadType.equals("fromDB"))
        {
            request.setAttribute("activeTab", "fromDatabase");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
```

Part of `index.jsp` is

```
<div class="navbar btn-navbar">
            <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#datacollector" target="main"
                        data-toggle="tab">Data Collector</a></li>
                    <li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType <c:if test="${activeTab == 'fromDatabase'}">active</c:if>" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromDatabase" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Database</a></li>
                    <li id="fromFile" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromFiles" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            File</a></li>
                    <li id="email" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromEmail" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Email</a></li>
                    <li id="webServices" class="selectDataloadType"
                        style="display: none;"><a href="#fromWebServices"
                        target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load Web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#datamap" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data
                            Map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#schedule" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
```

**LI** with id *fromDB* is setting the class attribute to active if the session attribute is 'fromDatabase' But its not working as it is not taking that part as code.
Here is the index.jsp

[image]

It is showing the code in page, so its not taking it. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not setting the class attribute correctly... The class attribute of the LI tag is `selectDataloadType [space] active`, so eventually it is just `selectDataloadType` I think...

Why not something like:

```
<li id="fromDB" <c:if test="${activeTab == 'fromDatabase'}">class="active"</c:if>...
```

You can use `choose` instead of `if` if you need to have a class attruibute in any case...

Comment: Actually I got its answer [Se answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15787274/2189617)